# AngularJS - How to change order of divs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How do I change the order `div` elements are displayed in given a preferred order? I am making my application in AngularJS, so pure JavaScript or Angular based answers are welcome.

Here's what my html looks like:

```
<div id="A">{{content for A}}</div>
<div id="B">{{content for B}}</div>
<div id="C">{{content for C}}</div>
```

In my script there are variables that describe preferred order:

```
orderOfA = 2;
orderOfB = 3;
orderOfC = 1;
```

I want to render the contents so, based on the above values for example, the order of `div` is `C`, `A`, `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built-in [OrderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter for ng-repeat

in your controller

```
$scope.values = [{"name": "valueA", order: 2}
  ,{"name": "valueB", order: 3}
  ,{"name": "valueC", order: 1} ]
```

in view

```
<div ng-repeat="value in values | orderBy: 'order'">
   {{value.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the content in each `div` is not identical. Each `div` has distinct html inside. So `ng-repeat` would not work.

Comment: The fact that you are seeking a dynamic means to order the content suggests that the data has some common order-able aspect. Define that first, then figure out how to extract it and this will be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Awakening Byte's answer, you can use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) to bind HTML.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.elements = [
    {html: "<div id='A'>Div A</div>", order: 2},
    {html: "<div id='B'>Div B</div>", order: 3},
    {html: "<div id='C'>Div C</div>", order: 1}
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <div ng-repeat="elem in elements | orderBy:'order'" ng-bind-html="elem.html">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/V0YOWfqEpQKviooKGR7V?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
      <div id="A">Content of A</div>
      <div id="B">Content of B</div>
      <div id="C">Content of C</div> 
 </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var orDerPrecedence = [{"A":2},{"B":3},{"C":1}];

   orDerPrecedence = orDerPrecedence.sort(function(a, b) {
       var valueOfA =  Object.keys(a).map(function(key){return a[key]})
       var valueOfB =  Object.keys(b).map(function(key){return b[key]})
       return (valueOfA > valueOfB ? 1 : (valueOfA < valueOfB) ? -1 : 0);

    });  
    var numericallyOrderedDivs = [];
    for(element in orDerPrecedence){
        numericallyOrderedDivs[numericallyOrderedDivs.length] = jQuery("#"+Object.keys(orDerPrecedence[element]));           
    }

    $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
```